# My tests dont want to run, only shows window for very short time

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I'm currently learning how write tests, and when I'm trying to run test in PowerShell by using command "py manage.py test" then nothing happend, except showing window in whom something is written, but this window last for so short amount of time that is impossible to read anything from this window

This is my test.py

```
from django .test import TestCase

from ..models import Category


class CategoryModelTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
    Category.objects.create(name='Armors', slug='Armors', description='')

    def test_name_label(self):
        category = Category.object.get(id=1)
        field_label = category._meta.get_field('name').verbose_name
        self.assertEqual(field_label, 'name')

    def test_slug_label(self):
        category = Category.object.get(id=1)
        field_label = category._method.get_field('slug').verbose_name
        self.assertEqual(field_label, 'slug')

    def test_description_label(self):
        category = Category.object.get(id=1)
        field_label = category._method_get_field('description').verbose_name
        self.assertEqual(field_label, 'description')

    def test_name_max_length(self):
        category = Category.object.get(id=1)
        max_length = category._method.get_field('name').max_length
        self.assertEqual(max_length, '25')

    def test_slug_max_length(self):
        category = Category.object.get(id=1)
        max_length = category._method_get_field('slug').max_length
        self.assertEqual(max_length, '25')
```

Localization of my test files:

```
encyclopedy(application in my project)
  model.py
  tests
    __init__.py
    test_models.py
```

Now I'm also see that there is option to run single tests by using PyCharm, and when I'm doing this then I get this error:

[image]

Comment: do you import your test class inside the `__inint__`?

Comment: If you mean this  __init__ in tests folder then No, this file is empty.

Comment: do it add the import

Comment: In __init__ add Something like that:  from . import test_models ?

Comment: yes in thw `__init__.py` add line `from .test_models import CategoryModelTest`

Comment: I did this and it's still same situation like before

Comment: Try to run PowerShell by hand, go to the directory of your project and run tests from there (using command mentioned above). Tests shouldn't then spawn new PowerShell window and one that you've opened will stay open. That way you can look at your test results and see what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Run powershell by hand" I always use power shell like this: I'm running PowerShell as Admin then im going to my env folder and running my eviorment then I'm going to my project folder where is manage.py file and there 'm using manage.py commands I dont know any other way to using PowerShell

Comment: You shouldn't have to add anything to the `__init__` file for tests. Your error says it can't find your app. Did you add your app to the settings?

Comment: Yes, my app is in INSTALLED_APPS